# content is null after the first dict()

Tags: python, django, dictionary

all:

In Django, I use these words to get the dict(q_a), but after the first dict(), the second one is null, how python works for that?

```
if request.method == "POST":
    q_a = request.POST.iteritems()
    print "type of q_a is %s" % q_a
    print "first dict(q_a) : %s " % dict(q_a)
    print "second dict(q_a): %s " % dict(q_a)
```

Here are the printouts:

```
type of q_a is <generator object _iteritems at 0x10c97ac30>
first dict(q_a) : {u'csrfmiddlewaretoken': u'KQA7K6MCwZWFsXO59pAOYOMyD92O9tYq', u'\u5b66\u9662': u'ss', u'\u59d3\u540d': u'ww', u'\u624b\u673a\u53f7\u7801': u''}
second dict(q_a): {}
```

Comment: That's a curious case of empty [iterator](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator).

Comment: `help(dict.iteritems)`.

Answer (score 2):

`request.POST.iteritems()` returns a generator object and it is exhausted after the first `dict` call.

```
if request.method == "POST":
    q_a = dict(request.POST.iteritems())
    print "first dict(q_a) : %s " % q_a
    print "second dict(q_a): %s " % q_a
```

Comment: **Wrong** term: `iteritems()` returns an [**iterator**](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-iterator) not [**generator**](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-generator). A generator also has methods like `send`, `close`, `throw` etc, but iterators don't.

Comment: That's right, thanks for the warning. I always mixed these terms as generators are also iterators but not vice versa.

Comment: Or you can change it to say `request.POST.iteritems()` returns an generator in Django,  because just mentioning `iteritems` part is a bit ambiguous.

Answer (score 0):

`q_a.iteritems()` is not a dictionary, it's a generator (as the print says). You can read more about them on the [Python Wiki](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), but in general you can iterate over them only once. After that, they will raise a `StopIteration` when you try to iterate over them again (as you do implicitly on you last line using `dict(q_a)`) which stops the loop. That's the reason why your call results in an empty dict.

Answer (score 0):

`.iteritems()` returns a  `iterator` object.

A `generator` is also an `iterator`.Generator will provide a sequence of values instead of one as in the case of iterators.

After the first call, it generates the values and then becomes empty. When you do second call, it will show an empty dict.

They are used when you need to use some particular values only once in your code.